# Prevent my website from running in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I don't want anyone to run my website in Internet Explorer, so I have added the following JavaScript call at the very beginning of the first .js file in my website, the file name is `screen.js`

**screen.js**

```
"use strict";

// block Internet Explorer as soon as possible
(function () {
    var isIE = /Trident|MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (isIE) {
        $('#blockIeModal').modal({ // <-- this is a modal that informs user that IE is not supported
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false
        });
    }
})()
```

I have the following .js files in my bundle (ASP.NET MVC syntax):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
    "~/Scripts/app/screen.js",
    "~/Scripts/app/common.js",
    "~/Scripts/app/url-builder.js",
    "~/Scripts/app/dropdown-common.js",
    "~/Scripts/app/bootstrap-table-common.js",
    "~/Scripts/app/numeric-format.js",
    "~/Scripts/app/megamenu-builder.js"));
```

The above code runs fine in Chrome but IE does not like some of the syntaxt that I have used in my .js file, for example in the screenshot below IE is complaining that there is a syntax error on *line 96* of `common.js`:

[image]

And because of this error I don't get the block IE popup which was supposed to be shown in the earlier call... I am confused because I though I am blocking IE at the very first step... so cannot understand why these Syntax errors are being shown?

### Update

I tried the approach suggested by @Nick Olay, see the screenshot below it still shows the loading dots which not supposed to be displayed in IE...

[image]

Comment: Well IE is going to break on JavaScript errors. Really nothing you can do other than detect IE11 on the server and send them to some other page. Or use babel and make it work.

Comment: IE 6 does not support [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: @fen1x: yes I understand that my syntax is not supported in IE... and I am not willing to change my syntaxt... I am trying to prevent users from running the website in IE.

Comment: In your have to primary `div` elements, one contains core site one the 'does not work in this browser'. In your `CSS` default core to `display: none;` and your message to `display:block`. Then use you non-IE compliant script to add a tag to the body element that switches this. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @epascarello, I managed to solve the issue by detecting the browser on the server side, here is what I have done:

Server side function to detect IE:

```
public static class BrowserHelper
{
    public static bool IsInternetExplorer()
    {
        var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
        if (userAgent.Contains("MSIE") || userAgent.Contains("Trident"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I build the HTML page, based on the above function call:

```
<body>
    @if (BrowserHelper.IsInternetExplorer())
    {
        <P>IE is an out dated browser...</p>
    }
    else
    {
         <!-- Actual Page HTML -->
    }
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it via HTML

```
<body>
<!--[if IE]>
  <p>Internet Explorer is not supported<p>
<![endif]-->

<![if !IE]>
  <p>Welcome</p>
<![endif]>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I tried your suggestion but when I open the page in IE, I see the wrong section in the output... I have included a screenshot in the question.

Comment: IE 10 and 11 doesn't support this conditionals

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `demonstration` of the principle I outlined in the comments above.

You can see we default our `main-app` `div` to `display:none;`

We then use code that will NOT run in IE to add a class to the container, in this case I used a `div` to toggle.

```js
const showApp = (cssToUse = "show") => {
  document.querySelector(".dummy-body").classList.add(cssToUse);
};

showApp("show");
```

```css
.main-app {
  display: none;
}

.warning {
  display: block;
}

.show .main-app {
  display: block;
}

.show .warning {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy-body">
  <div class="main-app">
      <p>This is the app</p>
  </div>
  <div class="warning">
      <p>Site does not run in this browser</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that my JavaScript has syntax error in IE so I cannot use a solution that relies on JavaScript.

Comment: No you miss the point. If the code fails it will show `Site does not work`. It will only show the app if your script works

Comment: Thanks I see your approach... but I still think this is a hacky solution... as the website is going to show *"IE not supported"* by default... which means any error or future bug in .js files would result in: *"IE not supported"*... and this message could be shown in any browser...

Comment: Oh for sure. Server side is definitely a better solution. Was just that you did not want to change your code syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I do it. I let the page load but if the user clicks anything or tries to do any sort of key press, those actions don't work and it harrasses them with alerts saying to switch. No HTML updates needed.

```
function disableIE() {

    function isIE() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        return (ua.indexOf('MSIE') > -1 || ua.indexOf('Trident') > -1) && !window.chrome;
    };

    if(isIE()){
        alert('This window does not support Internet Explorer, and basic functions on this screen will not work properly. Please switch to a modern browser.')
        document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("IE not allowed. Please use a modern browser.");
        }, true);
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("IE not allowed. Please use a modern browser.");
        }, true);
    }
}
```